# How to recover Ubuntu grub loader from Windows

Tags: grub2

I have installed Ubuntu os after that I have installed the windows 7 in another partition.
But Windows 7 is working fine but Ubuntu grub loader is not there. I tried to installed dual OS in different partitions only. Then why the Ubuntu is not loading. 
Can anyone have solution to get the Ubuntu.

Comment: In my case there is no option to go to the ubuntu os it's directly booting to the windows 7 any help pleas!

Comment: Can you boot from the Live CD again, as per the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install GRUB on the same partition as Windows:

1) Boot with Ubuntu Live CD (or USB)

2) Open terminal (command prompt)

3) Type:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

You will get a list of partitions, similar to the following list:

```
/dev/sda1 13 102400 de Dell Utility
/dev/sda2 * 13 1926 15360000 7 HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3 1926 30892 232676566 7 HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4 30893 60802 240245761 5 Extended
/dev/sda5 30893 59584 230467584 83 Linux
/dev/sda6 59585 60802 9777152 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Ubuntu partition is the one with the name "Linux" (not necessarily the one with the star, although could be). The Windows partition will typically be the one with the NTFS.

The Linux partition in this example (but you should try on either the Linux or the Windows partition. I believe in your case it would work on the Windows partition), is on '/dev/sda5' so we have to mount it:

4) Replace in the following command 'sda5' with the partition name in your case:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

5) And then install grub:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

6) Reboot and verify that all is working fine.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Windows is greedy and rewrites the master boot record to only point to itself, making it so that it bypasses GRUB and Ubuntu.  Typically, Ubuntu should be installed after Windows, but it's okay.

Burn [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) .iso to a disk and load and run it after Windows is installed. It'll restore the boot log and you'll see GRUB again and everything should be happy.

If you want in on a USB, since it seems Windows is working for you, use [this](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) tool to take the .iso you've downloaded and stick it on a usb. [Here's](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) some offical documentation which conveniently recommends the same thing.